# Stumped by deceptively smple initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $x>0$, solve the initial value problem,

$$x\log{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = y\log{x}$$

with $y(1)=2$, giving $y(x)$ explicitly in terms of $x$.

Comment: Differentiate $ln(x)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rearrange your equation by dividing by $xy$ such that

$\frac{\log{y}}{y}dy=\frac{\log{x}}{x}dx$

All that's left is to integrate both sides by making a substitution, noting the derivative of $\log{u}$ with respect to $u$ is $\frac{1}{u}$.

Then, use your initial condition to uniquely determine your solution $y(x)$.

Comment: Following this thru I get y = 2x. However, substitution of this back into the ode does not work ! Perhaps it's my algebra here !

Comment: @Callie12 Since you do not show your work there is no one other than you who can check what you've done wrong.

Comment: @Callie12 I think you are forgetting that when you integrate, you are getting $\log^2$ terms, not just $\log$, hence you shouldn't get a linear solution.

Comment: Yip, you are right ! Thank you. I was taking $\log^2(x)$ terms and then using power rule for logs which I now see is totally wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Rewrite your equation as

$$ \log y \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} = \log x \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} \implies \log y \, \mathrm{d}(\log y) = \log x \, \mathrm{d} (\log{x})$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

After the integration, you should get $\log^2y=\log^2x+c$. This translates into $y=e^{\sqrt{log^2x+c}}$. Now apply the initial condition and find $c$.